# Software to extract video, audio or subtitles from a Matroska (.mkv) file?

Tags: gratis, video, audio, data-extraction, mkv

I'm looking for **free** program that allows to extract video, audio or subtitles from `MKV` file separately. I'm using **Windows 10 Pro (x64)** on my desktop.

Can you suggest program that have such functionality and will work on **Windows 10 x64**?

Answer (score 1):

[FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) can do what you need, *and a lot more*, from the command line under Windows, OS-X & Linux.  It is free, gratis & open source.

Because it is so powerful you will probably have to spend some time reading the documentation but from a given input file you can specify which video, audio and subtitle streams you wish to output, in what format.

There are a number of GUI interfaces for FFMPEG but they do limit what you can do, (sometimes sensibly), and quite a few programs use FFMPEG as a back end to do the heavy lifting.